# Assign output of EJS include tag to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

My footer HTML is in the file footer.ejs. On another page, I want to append this HTML dynamically with JavaScript.

The code below doesn't work. Is there a way to assign a template output to a JavaScript variable?

```
var footer = <%= include footer %>;
$('.test').after(footer);
```

The templates are rendered on the back-end (Node) and sent to front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enclose the tag in `'`:

```
var footer = '<%= include footer %>';
```

Comment: Got ```SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in test.ejs while compiling ejs```